# Update error (Err:7 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf Packages)

Tags: update

by runnign `sudo apt-get update -y` command i get this errors:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get update -y
Get:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch InRelease [15.0 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease [25.4 kB]        
Get:3 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/contrib Sources [75.2 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch/main armhf Packages [220 kB]
Get:5 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/non-free Sources [125 kB]
Get:6 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main Sources [9722 kB]  
Get:7 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf Packages [11.7 MB]
Get:8 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/contrib armhf Packages [56.9 kB]
Ign:7 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf Packages     
Get:7 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf Packages [16.4 MB]
Ign:7 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf Packages     
Get:7 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf Packages [61.5 MB]
Err:7 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch/main armhf Packages     
  Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) Error writing to file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Fetched 21.9 MB in 10min 47s (33.8 kB/s)                                       
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/dists/stretch/main/binary-armhf/Packages  Error writing to output file - write (28: No space left on device) Error writing to file - write (28: No space left on device) [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

what dose it means?

Thanks.

Comment: No space left on device!

Answer (score 2):

Your disk is full. Depending on why - you will find lots of suggestions to delete excess if you search.

You could start by running `sudo apt-get clean`

Then **STOP** using `apt-get` and use `sudo apt update` instead.